# Gutenberg add extra attributes to custom format

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm creating a custom format (adding a custom option to the format toolbar) using the following guide: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/format-api/

```
import { registerFormatType, toggleFormat } from '@wordpress/rich-text';
import { RichTextToolbarButton } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
 
const MyCustomButton = ( { isActive, onChange, value } ) => {
    return (
        <RichTextToolbarButton
            icon="editor-code"
            title="Sample output"
            onClick={ () => {
                onChange(
                    toggleFormat( value, {
                        type: 'my-custom-format/sample-output',
                    } )
                );
            } }
            isActive={ isActive }
        />
    );
};
 
registerFormatType( 'my-custom-format/sample-output', {
    title: 'Sample output',
    tagName: 'samp',
    className: null,
    edit: MyCustomButton,
} );
```

This creates, for example: `Hello <samp>world</samp>`

How can i add extra attributes to the new format? For example if i want to add a data attribute. I tried:

```
registerFormatType( 'my-custom-format/sample-output', {
    title: 'Sample output',
    tagName: 'samp',
    className: null,
    'data-custom': 'Some value',
    edit: MyCustomButton,
} );
```

But `data-custom` does not show in the HTML output.

Comment: The format API does not support custom attributes - why do you want to add a static data attribute?

Comment: i think it does support it. there are many reasons to add a data attribute. I am making it static in the example for simplicity

Comment: for example maybe i want to create an inline tooltip format which can use extra attributes for custom js

Comment: The documentation for the format settings object is [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/rich-text/src/register-format-type.js) at the top of the file. It makes no mention of any other possible parameters. It doesn't look like extraneous parameters are stripped though - they should still end up in state. I'll dig around a little further. If you're writing custom JS for a tooltip, I'd think you might as well code those settings into the JS based on className, as they would be static for all instances of the format anyway.

Comment: I don't see this documented anywhere, but try adding your custom attributes in an object in the `attributes` property of your format type object. It looks like [this issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/18490) is discussing a means to dynamically change attributes at front-end page-load - some of the code there implies you may also be able to set the attributes editor-side when `toggleFormat()` is called.

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding to the attributes object and it is showing in the html. No errors. Hopefully it will work in future updates.

Comment: Awesome!! I'll add it as an answer after I look around a little more. Everything I'm seeing indicates that this should be a stable feature moving forward :)

Comment: Ok I added an answer, although I am not sure how the code works exactly. I will leave it open to comments and edits.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add the attribute by passing it in `attributes` through the `registerFormatType` settings:

```
attributes: {
   'custom-attr': 'custom-attr'
},
```

then in `edit()`:

```
toggleFormat( value, {
    attributes: {
      'custom-attr': 'Hello world'
    },
} )
```

I don't know how exactly it all works together because I could not find detailed explanations in the current documentation.

Another great feature would be the ability to add extra HTML markup in custom formats but I could not find any examples. For example:

```
<div custom-attr="Hello world"><div class="an-extra-div"></div>Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>
```